# Making the [connections-puzzle] tag more relevant?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've been curating the [connections-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connections-puzzle) tag recently, predominantly to remove instances of it that have been used with [connect-wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connect-wall) puzzles, since this isn't the intended usage (mainly on my own puzzles, it turns out – I’ve been culprit #1!). In fact, the true intended usage is my question here...

The tag excerpt (which shows up on hover-over) says just “A puzzle involving making connections between several clues in a list.” However, the full details in the tag info (never updated since it was first created in March 2015) say:

> “This tag is for puzzles where **a list of several items is given, each one connected cryptically to the next**. The solver's task is to work out what the items are and how they are connected.”

I’ve reached the point in my curation where I’ve picked all the low-hanging fruit – fixing the obviously incorrect uses and the connect-wall over-uses – and instead I’m finding lots of puzzles that use a phrase like ‘spot the connection’, but which didn’t really fulfil any kind of ‘cryptic’ (in the sense of ‘mysterious’) element, as per the tag description. Often, these puzzles comprise a simple list of words or a set of images which have some kind of shared connection, and the point of the puzzle is to unearth it – see, for instance, [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106872/what-do-these-words-have-in-common-season-12-episode-254) and [this other one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116886/can-you-find-the-connection-between-these-four-images).

These types of puzzles are likely the ones that jump to your mind when you think of a 'connection puzzle' (I know they are for me). However, as this tag's description is currently worded, it appears it was initially created more for puzzles like [this one in 2015](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8886/link-the-hints-to-solve-this-one-starting-with-michael-jackson), where there is a real element of mystery around a series of connections between obscured items.

The thing is, that style of question is *really specific*, very niche, and has barely ever been used, whilst questions of the form “What connects the words in this list?” are far more common and – I would say – probably the most appropriate usage of this particular tag, which is a natural one to gravitate towards using when creating a puzzle based on connecting items in a list (as, indeed, it has proved to be for many puzzle setters here over the years). **I propose to improve the tag description to reflect this better** – specifically, to word it in a way that these 'connect the items in a list' questions are definitely included in the intended usage, because right now they 'don't seem cryptic enough' to be covered by what the description currently says at face value.

I am happy to make these improvements myself, but before doing anything I wish to check: *Does anybody foresee any issues with this changing-the-description/purpose-of-the-tag-to-match-its-most-common-usage idea?*

Comment: For what it's worth, this seems fine to me.

Comment: Huh. Apparently I created that tag wiki and excerpt back in 2015, but I've totally forgotten doing so and didn't even remember that the tag existed until seeing this meta post. As you've been doing the legwork of curating the tag and making sure it's used consistently, I'd say you know best how it should be used, so go for it.

Comment: Thanks @Randal'Thor - I wondered if it might have been one of those tags set up when the site was young to cater for some perceived use cases, but which over time has actually been found more relevant to a broader set of puzzles... Unless any serious objections appear, I'll get this sorted this week :)

Comment: Are you also proposing a tag name change or would that be a separate question?

Comment: @bobble Nah, just the description. I think 'connections-puzzle' works fine right now, but we can always think about it later if people are keen to...

Comment: Tangent: So "connect-wall" means a puzzle like [Connections](https://www.nytimes.com/games/connections), and "connections-puzzle" means something different? Arguably _that's_ the confusing aspect of all this... :)

Comment: @Quuxplusone The NYT's Connections puzzle is very much a newcomer to the scene. Their puzzle is identical in format (to all intents and purposes) to the connecting wall on the BBC's Only Connect, which has been around since 2008 and which spawned the "connect-wall" tag here. "Connections" as a word is a very good fit for a 'what is the connection' type puzzle - it's just unfortunate for this tag that the NYT chose that name for their puzzle :) The tag details will make it clear either way, but we can look at synonymising it too if it becomes an issue. (Thanks for mentioning it...)